# EF Core LINQ GROUPBY Then Select to get more than one properties of the entity

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have 2 tables Outlet and Order with below schemas:

```
Outlet          Order
------    -------------------
Id              Id
Name            Name
                OrderCompletedTime
                NextOrderDueTime
                OutletIds
```

Earlier when I wanted to get the NextOrderDueTime for each outlet using entity framework core, I did:

```
return _dbAccessor.RequestContext.MyDbContext.Order
                .Where(i => i.OutletId == _dbAccessor.RequestContext.OutletId &&
                            !i.IsRemoved && i.NextOrderDueTime.HasValue)
                .GroupBy(i => i.OutletId)
                .Select(g => new { OutletId = g.Key, NextOrderDueTime = g.Min(x => x.NextOrderDueTime) })
                .ToDictionary(i => i.OutletId, i => i.NextOrderDueTime);
```

Now on the UI we need to make this due time as link and wants user to get navigated to that Order details page based on order id

How can I change the above query to also return OrderId along with time?

My thoughts:

1. Change return type of method from `Dictionary<int, DateTimeOffset?>` to `Dictionary<int, Tuple<int,DateTimeOffset?>>`
2. I tried changing the Linq query to :

```
return _dbAccessor.RequestContext.MyDbContext.Order
                .Where(i => i.OutletId == _dbAccessor.RequestContext.OutletId &&
                            !i.IsRemoved && i.NextOrderDueTime.HasValue)
                .GroupBy(i => i.OutletId)
                   .Select(g =>
                       new
                       {
                           OutletId = g.Key,
                           NextOrderDueTime = g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NextOrderDueTime == g.Min(y => y.NextOrderDueTime)).NextOrderDueTime,
                           NextOrderId = g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NextOrderDueTime == g.Min(y => y.NextOrderDueTime)).OrderId
                       })
                       .ToDictionary(i => i.OutletId, i => new Tuple<int, DateTimeOffset?>(i.NextOrderId, i.NextOrderDueTime));
```

But this throws exception at runtime?

Please help to let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .GroupBy(...).Select(...).ToDictionary(...); cannot be converted to SQL since EF Core 3.0.

Due to the breaking change in EF Core 3.0. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes , EF Core 3.0 will throw exception to make sure you know that all records in Order will be fetched from database before grouping and map to Dictionary.

I was able to get my query working as below:

```
return _dbAccessor.RequestContext.MyDbContext.Order
                .Where(i => i.OutletId == _dbAccessor.RequestContext.OutletId &&
                            !i.IsRemoved && i.NextOrderDueTime.HasValue).AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(i => i.OutletId)
                   .Select(g =>
                       new
                       {
                           OutletId = g.Key,
                           NextOrderDueTime = g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NextOrderDueTime == g.Min(y => y.NextOrderDueTime)).NextOrderDueTime,
                           NextOrderId = g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NextOrderDueTime == g.Min(y => y.NextOrderDueTime)).OrderId
                       })
                       .ToDictionary(i => i.OutletId, i => new Tuple<int, DateTimeOffset?>(i.NextOrderId, i.NextOrderDueTime));
```

The same can be done as shown in another answer by just adding AsEnumerable() before GroupBy:

```
 _dbAccessor.RequestContext.MyDbContext.Order
                .Where(i => i.OutletId == _dbAccessor.RequestContext.OutletId &&
                            !i.IsRemoved && i.NextOrderDueTime.HasValue).AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(i => i.OutletId)
                  .Select(g => new { 
  OutletId = g.Key, 
  NextOrder = g.OrderBy(x => x.NextOrderDueTime).FirstOrDefault() 
})
.Select(s => new {
  s.OutletId,
  NextOrderId = NextOrder.Id,
  NextOrder.NextOrderDueTime,
  NextOrderName = NextOrder.Name
})`enter code here`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just take the entire order along with the outletid when you return:

```
.Select(g => new { 
  OutletId = g.Key, 
  NextOrder = g.OrderBy(x => x.NextOrderDueTime).FirstOrDefault() 
})
```

You could select on this to take multiple properties from the order:

```
.Select(g => new { 
  OutletId = g.Key, 
  NextOrder = g.OrderBy(x => x.NextOrderDueTime).FirstOrDefault() 
})
.Select(s => new {
  s.OutletId,
  NextOrderId = NextOrder.Id,
  NextOrder.NextOrderDueTime,
  NextOrderName = NextOrder.Name
})
```

etc..

The main thing to appreciate is that grouping gives you an object that has a key, but itself is a list of all things that have that key, so if you order the list by something like the DUeDat and take the first thing then you have an entire object with the lowest duedate from which you can take various things

Comment: Invalid Operation Exception is thrown when I used the above LINQ. Exception message says: ' The LINQ .... could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().